# jquery to modify a link on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible with jquery to use DOM to find an a link inside a div, such as

```
<div id="something">
<a href="somewhere" title="something">
<img>
</a>
</div>
```

and append a datum to the link - in my case a google events tag:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', ' PDF Downloads', ‘Click', 'SEO For Beginners');"
```

dynamically to the a link so that the end result would be:

```
<div id="something">
<a href="somewhere" title="something" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', ' PDF Downloads', ‘Click', 'SEO For Beginners');">
<img>
</a>
</div>
```

thank you for your time; any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be better if you just catch desired element with selector and bind a function to it, instead of binding a function directly in DOM.

```js
$('#something a').click(function() {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', ' PDF Downloads', 'Click', 'SEO For Beginners']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something">
  <a href="somewhere" title="something">
    <img>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let tag = $('#something').find('a');
tag[0].onClick = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', ' PDF Downloads', ‘Click', 'SEO For Beginners')";
```

you find the div you need by id, and by using function `find()` you serach your `a` tag.

After that you just refer to the DOM object of your tag by `tag[0]` and set `onClick` whatever you like.

Comment: You might want to add a few lines explaining how this works so that it's easier for the OP to add to his existing code. Thanks.

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your genereal *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding your answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: wrote some explanation, couldn't do it earlier i had to leave work :)

Comment: i am asuming instead of `let..` i can just name the var like usual?

Comment: @HollerTrain yes